# Precompile Hogan.js Templating Server Side ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, template-engine, hogan.js

I'm taking a look at Hogan.js by Twitter.

http://twitter.github.com/hogan.js/

They talk about being able to precompile templates via the server which I understand can be a perf gain.

Currently every time I render the template I perform the following after an AJAX hit to the server to get data:

```
     var template = Hogan.compile($('#seasonsTmpl').html());
     $('#main').html(template.render(data));
```

Given the following template:

```
<script type="text/html" id="seasonsTmpl">

     <ul>
    {{#season}}
        <li>{{.}}</li>
    {{/season}}
    </ul>

</script>
```

What can I do to "precompile" server side using an ASP.MVC backend? Is this not possible as it seems to be centered around using `Node.js`?

Answer (score 1):

You have the right idea to optimize your templates. There are two options, and the choice probably depends on whether you want to render your templates client-side or server-side.

If you want to render them client-side, you can do a true precompile using Hogan.js. Yes, this does not run on .NET, but I think you've misunderstood when precompilation is possible. Rather than expecting it to happen on each web request, or page load, you can compile your templates up-front as part of your build process. You *will* need to install node and npm to set this up, but you only need to run this locally on your own machine, or a build box if you use one. Whenever you update your templates, you would run Hogan again to update the output file. The compiled output will be a JavaScript file full of functions that are optimized for later use. These functions include your template strings, along with the logic to render the data a la Mustache. You can then include the output file just like any other JavaScript include, or include it with the other sources for minification if you do that.

The second option is to render the templates server-side. This is different than precompilation, the server will compile and render the templates again for each web request. Step away from Hogan.js and look at a .NET alternative such as Nustache. The great thing about Mustache is it has a spec and has been ported to several server-side languages.

There's a fundamental difference in these options in terms of where the rendering happens. You might even want to leverage both approaches in certain scenarios, say if you want to render the initial page load server-side using Nustache, but have dynamic elements that must be rendered in the browser using templates precompiled through Hogan.

More info:
[Nustache on Github](https://github.com/jdiamond/Nustache)

I hope you find this helpful!